# How to make promises wait each other without using async/await pair?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am working on old project that doesn't supports ES6 standards.

For ease of understanding i will write the code i am trying to reach, Please translate the following code without using async/await pair.

```
async function doSomeCalls(arrayWithNeededCalls){
    for(let i = 0; i < arrayWithNeededCalls.length; i++){
      await makeSomeCall(arrayWithNeededCalls[i]);
      console.log("Call: ", i, " Completed going to next one");
    }
}
```

I tried to use

```
  Promise.all()
```

But it doesn't wait one promise to be completed before running second one.

Comment: Hi, could you add what you've tried so far ? This is not a coding service, try to solve your problem and if you are having issues, we can help you.

Comment: arrayWithNeededCalls map to Promises and use `Promise.all` for parallel or reduce arrayWithNeededCalls to one promise

Comment: Hello @Nicolas this code is pretty much everything i am trying to achieve but in older ways for legacy project.

Comment: Aren't there tools out there that can translate newer features to older standards? Babel or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to wait for your promises one by one, in order, so you should use recursion:

```
const doSomeCalls = (arrayWithNeededCalls) => {
  const processCall = (index) => makeSomeCall(arrayWithNeededCalls[index]).then(res => {
    console.log(`Call ${index} Completed going to next one`);
    if (index < arrayWithNeededCalls.length) {
      return processCall(index+1);
    }
  });
  return processCall(0);
}
```

Comment: Will this solution wait first promise to complete before go to another one?

Comment: `Promise.all(...promiseArray)`; will execute them simultaneously, not one by one

Comment: This will run all promises concurrently.

Comment: @ChrisG exactly, therefore it is wrong solution. In the question one by one is required

Comment: @LevanLomia I updated my response to a recursive solution that runs all the promises one after the other.

Comment: Recursion is on option, you could also do this with reduce.

Comment: @HMR Yes, you have a nice solution as well.  You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @LevanLomia Thanks for noticing.  I have updated to fix syntax issues.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
[HRM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641941/hmr) comment looks much better:

Since OP is ignoring the value(s) returned by the promises you can do:

`arrayWithNeededCalls.reduce( (result, item) => result.then(() => makeSomeCall(item)), Promise.resolve() );`

OLD:
In case if you need to run them one by one:

```
makeSomeCall(arrayWithNeededCalls[0])
    .then(() => makeSomeCall(arrayWithNeededCalls[1]))
    .then(() => makeSomeCall(arrayWithNeededCalls[2]))
    .then(() => makeSomeCall(arrayWithNeededCalls[3]))
```

But if you don't know exact promises but use just array of them - `await` is the best solution

Comment: You should redue arrayWithNeededCalls to one promise if you want to not parallel process them, then he amount of items in arrayWithNeededCalls can be dynamic.

Comment: @HMR could you explain how to reduce it one by one? (not concurrently)

Comment: Since OP is ignoring the value(s) returned by the promises you can do: `arrayWithNeededCalls.reduce(
  (result, item) => result.then(() => makeSomeCall(item)),
  Promise.resolve()
);
`

Comment: @HMR yes, it looks nice

Comment: You can use it in your answer

Comment: @Bergi thanks, just missed